# StAX return unknown case

Tags: java, xml, xpath, sax, stax

i am using StAX for processing huge xml file. as shown below in the code, in the switch-case there is a default condition. when i run the code
the text in the default case prints the following:

```
unhandled case4
```

what is case4? i tried to java docs for Stax but i could not find it...it seems that XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT has constant int value of 1
and XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT has constant value of 2...but which one is 4?

**code**:

```
for (int event = mStAXParser.next(); event != XMLStreamConstants.END_DOCUMENT; event = mStAXParser.next()) {

        switch (event) {
        case XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT:

            Log.d(TAG, "main", "@START_ELEMENT");
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getLocalName(): "+mStAXParser.getLocalName());
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getAttributeCount(): "+mStAXParser.getAttributeCount());
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getAttributeLocalName(): "+mStAXParser.getAttributeLocalName(1));
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getAttributeValue(): "+mStAXParser.getAttributeValue(0));

            break;

        case XMLStreamConstants.END_ELEMENT:
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "@END_ELEMENT");
            Log.d(TAG, "main", "getLocalName():"+mStAXParser.getLocalName());

            break;

        default:
            Log.wtf(TAG, "main", "unhandled case" + event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS, it is characters which has the value `4`.

Comment: yes true...but would u please tell me how to display that character trapped in the case XMLStreamConstants.CHARACTERS? i want to display which character is that

Comment: Use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getText to get a String with the characters of the text node on which the reader is positioned.